# syntax: multiple type declarations for "width"

Tags: julia

I am using julia 0.6, my code used to run on 0.5.2 just fine, now that I port it I get this error

`syntax: multiple type declarations for "width"`

Now when I `grep -rn "width" *` on the whole package I get this result

```
coolFile.jl:11:    local const width::Int64 = Int64(sqrt(modulation))
coolFile.jl:12:    local const mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64} = (width, width)
coolFile.jl:19:      local const minValue::Float64 = minimumDistance / 2 -  minimumDistance * width / 2
coolFile.jl:20:      for y in 1:width
coolFile.jl:22:        for x in 1:width
coolFile.jl:44:      for i in 1:2:width
coolFile.jl:45:        local const startIndex = 1 + width*i
coolFile.jl:46:        inplaceReverse(startIndex:(startIndex + width - 1))
```

I see only one declaration and definition of width. All this code is inside the constructor. Line 11 is the first line of the constructor body. Am I just blind and wrote `width::Bananas = -69105` somewhere?

Comment: did you try to import the coolFile.jl (or the function within) more than once in the same session?

Comment: The `::Int64` after `width` is not needed, the type is determined by `Int64(sqrt(modulation))`. The error message is a little unclear.

Comment: @AlexanderMorley no and it should not matter, since it is a local variable scoped withing the constructor.

Comment: @DanGetz I removed the Int64(...) I agree that it is not necessary. Still the same error message.

Comment: fair enough. Difficult to tell anything else without a reproducible example. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Nozdrum what is not needed is the `::Int64` not the `Int64(...)`. Do: `local const width = Int64(sqrt(modulation))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `local const` on all my variables is causing the issue. I don't know why, but removing one specifier ( does not matter which one ) causes the error with its useless error message to disappear.

There is also no mention about any of that in the release notes of 0.6.

Since someone downvoted me ( good job man!, downvoting a solution). Here is a selfcontained example.

```
struct Shit
    a::Int64
    function Shit(b::Int64)
        local const c::Int64 = b * 3
        new(c)
    end
end

ERROR: LoadError: syntax: multiple type declarations for "c"
Stacktrace:
 [1] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:569
 [2] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [3] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:305
 [4] _start() at .\client.jl:371
while loading ~\shit.jl, in expression starting on line 1
```

Removing either `local`, `const` or the type `::Int64` will result in the code working again.

Comment: Ah.. so removing `::Int64` does work. I thought it was only on the specific version I was running.